# Problem Atmel Studio 7 with uploading

Tags: arduino-ide, uploading, atmel-studio

I have a problem with the interworking between Atmel Studio 7 and Arduino IDE 1.6.10.

I recently upgraded from IDE 1.0 to 1.6.10 and I can no longer upload my code to the Arduino. Everything works including compiling and it does recognise my COM3 port. Atmel Studio is configured for no external programmer.

When I compile with the Arduino IDE it *does* upload the code. My question is what goes wrong here, what do I need to do solve it. Thanks for your help

This the message I have in the end:

```
Compiling 'GridMonintor_V1R1' for 'Arduino Nano w/ ATmega328' Binary sketch size: 12,268 bytes (used 40% of a 30,720 byte maximum) (22.20 secs)

Minimum Memory Usage: 774 bytes (38% of a 2048 byte maximum) Uploading to I/O board using 'COM3'

avrdude: no programmer has been specified on the command line or the config file
         Specify a programmer using the -c option and try again
```

Comment: Switch on verbose so that we can see the upload command

Answer (score 1):

> ...Specify a programmer using the -c option and try again

For Arduino, the programmer switch must be `-c arduino`. The full arguments for `avrdude`, in the Atmel Studio 7 External Tools window, are:

```
-c arduino -p m328p -P COM3 -b 57600 -D -V -U flash:w:"$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).hex":a
```

See [avrdude options](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_4.html#Option-Descriptions).

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try the following command:
-C “C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\etc\avrdude.conf” -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM3 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).hex:i

where i is used at the end for intel. the one provided above by @flanker uses a

see this detailed tutorial [How to program Arduino using ATMEL Studio 7](http://eestuffs.com/2017/02/13/how-to-program-arduino-using-atmel-studio-7/)

Answer (score 0):

Switch on vMicro>Uploader>verbose then try the upload and post the output as a .txt file in a new thread in the visualmicro.com forum.

http://www.visualmicro.com/forums

Because you are using the Visual Micro plugin the forum is the best place to see help.

We will also check that you have configured the new arduino location against the arduino 1.6.x option in Visual Micro and not the Arduino 1.0. option as you had it originally. In fact you can have both IDE versions configured in Visual Micro at the same time and switch between them using the tool bar.

Thanks